# Bytelandian Gold Coin explaination?

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying The Bytelandian Gold coin problem mentioned here - http://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS/ here is one of its solution-

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int a[30][19];  //1
long int recur(long int n, int i, int j);
int main()
{
    long int n;
    int i, j;
    while (scanf("%lld", &n) != EOF)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 30;i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 19; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0;
        long int v = recur(n, 0, 0);
        printf("%lld\n", v);
    }
    return 0;
}
long int recur(long int n, int i, int j)
{
    if (n <12 )  //2
        return n;
    else if (!a[i][j])
    {
        long int t = recur(n / 2, i + 1, j) + recur(n / 3, i, j + 1) + recur(n / 4, i + 2, j);
        a[i][j] = t;
    }

    return a[i][j];
}
```

In this code I cannot understand two points-
1-the size of array a[30][19] which is based on the maximum number of times the maximum value of the input number is divisible by 2 or 3 for which they use some log base 2 or 3 formula to find.Can someone please explain this formula,is this some mathematical property if yes where can I find more information about it.
2-to stop the recursion  n<12 condition was used as all numbers below 12 will have values equal to itself as max value.I cannot understand how it was found.I mean how they find 12 is the limiting value also if I replaced the original recur function with this I get wrong answer-

```
long int recur(long int n, int i, int j)
{
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1) || (n == 2) )
        return n;
    else if (!a[i][j])
    {
        long int t = recur(n / 2, i + 1, j) + recur(n / 3, i, j + 1) + recur(n / 4, i + 2, j);
        a[i][j] = n> t ? n : t;
    }

    return a[i][j];
}
```

I would be grateful if someone please explains the above 2 points

Comment: note : `"%lld"` change to `"%ld"` for `long int`.

Comment: I did that but got wrong answer on submitting the solution after doing so.

Comment: <12 as a limit is demonstrated in the problem description.  for 11 or lower, you can't make more than 11.  For 12, you can make 13. Also, since the limit is 12, defining `a[27][17]` is sufficient for all use cases <= 1,000,000,000.  Basically, if you divide 10e9 by 2 27 times, you get a number less than 12 and terminate, and 10e9 divided by 4 17 times is the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. An upper limit for *i* results from the condition *2<sup>i</sup> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>* (the number of times 10<sup>9</sup> can be divided by 2 until reaching 1 is equal to the number of times 1 can be multiplied by 2 until reaching 10<sup>9</sup>); solving for *i* yields *i ≤ log<sub>2</sub>(10<sup>9</sup>)* ≅ 29.9.
   Another way to look at it is by expressing 10<sup>9</sup> as a binary number 111011100110101100101000000000<sub>2</sub>; this number has 30 digits, each integer division by 2 yields one digit less (removing the rightmost digit), so after 29 divisions we arrive at 1.
   As JohnH correctly stated in his comment above, the maximum value of *i* is still lower than 29, because the recursion doesn't go down to *n = 1*, but stops at *n < 12*.
   About the same goes for the upper limit of *j* and division by 3. 10<sup>9</sup> as a ternary number is 2120200200021010001<sub>3</sub>; this number has 19 digits; after 17 integer divisions by 3 we arrive at 21<sub>3</sub> = 7, where the recursion stops.
2. To find out that all numbers below 12 are equal to their maximum exchange amount, we can simply try them all out:

   ```
    n  n/2  n/3  n/4  sum of the 3 exchanged coins
    1   0    0    0    0
    2   1    0    0    1
    3   1    1    0    2
    4   2    1    1    4
    5   2    1    1    4
    6   3    2    1    6
    7   3    2    1    6
    8   4    2    2    8
    9   4    3    2    9
   10   5    3    2   10
   11   5    3    2   10
   12   6    4    3   13
   ```

   We see that 12 is the lowest number that yields a value higher than itself when exchanged.

   > if I replaced the original recur function with this I get wrong
   >   answer-

   From *n = 509607936* on you get "wrong answer" because `long int t` etc. overflows to negative values. Curiously enough, with the original `recur` function this error is compensated by another error, namely the wrong conversion specification `%lld` noted by BLUEPIXY. The program can be corrected by defining `a`, `recur`, `t` and `v` with type `unsigned long int` and using the appropriate conversion specification `%lu`.